# How to compile JS, CSS and HTML code into vuetify?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to build a website using vuetify and I want to build a Contact Form. I am using this github repository. 
https://github.com/jcottrell/vue-example-contact-form
How do I compile this into vuetify format which uses template tags and so on.
Or is a better/easier way of sending emails from vuejs?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to install the vue-cli.

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli

You'll be able to just type `vue init webpack` into your terminal and create a full featured webpack-based Vue project. Once you created the project you could simply copy the code from the repository you linked.

That's the easiest way to set up a full featured Vue project.